# Vertical timeline ios design

Tags: objective-c, ios7, timeline, vertical-scrolling

I want to develop a vertical timeline like this picture on my application
The idea is to put a date in the middle and bunch of pictures on both sides (pretty much like the screenshot)

[image]

The problem is that I don't really know where to start.
What I want is the middle vertical bar to be able to add 'node' on both sides left and right that contain a picture + caption

If I can have an element (like the date) on the middle bar too that would be great too.

Do you have any suggestions ?

Comment: Looks nice. You need to think about how the user will interact with it. You could use a scroll view with custom subviews, but a collection view will probably be better.

Comment: @luxsypher what have you figured out so far?

Comment: Something kind of like suggested by Wain.
The idea was drop but I did something with a scrollview 
a bar in the a middle (just a view with background and a fixed position) , and the bullets (time) are part of the subview, I alternated the content of the a subview on left then right, etc (i % 2) 
The size of the picture was scale on a rating I had, so some seems bigger etc